# Что нужно покрывать тестами, а что - нет?

Tags: php, юнит-тесты

Есть класс-парсер. В конструктор передаем номер пользователя, проверяем его, и если все нормально - создается экземпляр класса. Если данные неправильные - выбрасывается исключение и экземпляр не создается.

```
class Parser
    {
        private $apiUrl;
        private $userId;
        private $userName;
        private $userBirth;
        private $userAge;

        function __construct($userId){
            $url = 'https://www.example.com/api/'.$userId;

            $urlHeaders = get_headers($url);
            if ($urlHeaders[0] == 'HTTP/1.0 404 Not Found') {
                throw new Exception("Incorrect userId");
            } else {
                $this->userId = $userId;
                $this->apiUrl = $url;
            }
        }

        function parseData() {
            $json = file_get_contents($this->apiUrl);
            $data = json_decode($json, true);
            //...тут код парсера
        }

        function getName() {
            return $this->userName;
        }

        function getBirth() {
            return $this->userBirth;
        }

        function getAge() {
            return $this->userAge;
        }
    }
```

То есть, если экземпляр-таки создан, значит мы получили от API корректные данные. Нужно ли включать паранойю и проверять данные дополнительно, скажем в `parseData`? Или все-таки отдача правильных данных по корректному запросу - удел поставщика API?

Какие методы тут нужно покрывать тестами? Все? Даже простейшие, типа `getName`, `getAge`?

P.S.Пример написан отфонаря, чтобы не грузить вас простынями кода. В реальном проекте речь идет о Google API.

Comment: _"Или все-таки отдача правильных данных по корректному запросу - удел поставщика API?"_ - это, конечно, так, но вашим пользователям все равно, откуда вы берете эти данные. Если данные пришли корявые, если запрашиваемый сервис не работает, и все это повлияло на корректность работы вашего приложения - это ваш косяк. И если в функционал заложена обработка подобного поведения, то она должна быть покрыта тестами.

Comment: Окей, с этим разобрались. А что касается покрытия тестами простейших методов? Каждый метод должен быть покрыт? Ведь если мы получили правильные данные, правильно их распарсили, у нас в любом случае имеются корректные свойства класса на вывод.

Comment: Тут уже несколько хитрее. С одной стороны, любой публичный метод должен быть хотя бы раз вызван. С другой стороны, покрытие тестами только ради покрытия - бред, всегда есть более интересные вещи. Поэтому простейшие методы я либо пропускаю (поскольку в них очень сложно ошибиться, а косвенно они и так будут вызваны), либо пишу на них минимально возможное количество тестов.

Comment: @qtm ну если ты тестами покроешь проверку на корректность пришедших данных, а геттеры и сеттеры ссылаются туда, то это лишние проверки. Хотя тестами можно покрывать все, если ты параноик))

Comment: Вот примерно это я и хотел услышать. То есть, по максимуму проверяю данные и пишу тесты только на эти методы. Спасибо.